# postgres createdb locale woes

Tags: postgresql, locale

I am having a spot of trouble setting up a db due to the following :

```
$ createdb -E UTF-8 -p 5432 nominatim
createdb: database creation failed: ERROR:  encoding "UTF8" does not match locale "en_US"
DETAIL:  The chosen LC_CTYPE setting requires encoding "LATIN1".
ERROR: Error executing external command: createdb -E UTF-8 -p 5432 nominatim
```

In /etc/profile I set locale to en_US.UTF-8 and when I check 'locale' as postgres user (or my own user) all vars including LC_CTYPE are 'en_US.UTF-8'.  Also, I have run `sudo locale-gen en_US en_US.UTF-8`  and `sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales`.  Does anyone have a clue why LC_CTYPE seems to be falling back to en_US and not en_US.UTF-8?

Answer (score 1):

The default locale for a cluster is set by [`initdb`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/locale.html):

> Locale support is automatically initialized when a database cluster is
>   created using `initdb`. `initdb` will initialize the database cluster with
>   the locale setting of its execution environment by default [...] If you want to use
>   a different locale (or you are not sure which locale your system is
>   set to), you can instruct `initdb` exactly which locale to use by
>   specifying the `--locale` option.

You can override the default for a new database with [`createdb --locale`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-createdb.html).

If you really need to modify the default for an existing cluster, you can drop and recreate [`template1`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/manage-ag-templatedbs.html) with a different locale (see [this example](http://pgsql.inb4.se/2009/april/rebuild-template1.html)).

Comment: this did the trick. see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13115692/encoding-utf8-does-not-match-locale-en-us-the-chosen-lc-ctype-setting-requires  for explicit instructions for how to create the new db with utf-8 support